# getting the arguments of a parent function in R, with names

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function that captures the arguments of the function it is called from. For example,

```
get_args <- function () as.list( sys.call(sys.parent()) )[-1]

caller <- function (x, y, z) {
    get_args()
}
caller(1,2,3)

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2

[[3]]
[1] 3
```

sys.call() unfortunately does not add match parameter names with argument values, and I'd like to write a similar version of get_args that returns output similar to

```
caller2 <- function (x, y, z) {
    as.list( match.call() )[-1]
}
caller2(1,2,3)

$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] 2

$z
[1] 3
```

replacing "get_args()" with "match.call()" directly is not the solution I'm looking for, since in reality get_args will do some other things before returning its parent functions arguments.

I've tried to use match.call() with sys.parent() in several ways, but I can't get the function to return the arguments of caller; it just returns the arguments of get_args().

Is there any way to make get_args() return output identical to that of caller2 for the above test case? I know that naming the arguments manually is possible using formals(), but is this guaranteed to be equivelant?

If any clarification is needed, leave a comment below. Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

the aim of get_args() is to act as a user-friendly way of getting the arguments with which a function was called. Typing as.list( match.call() )[-1] gets old, but because match.call grabs the nearest function call it just gets the arguments of get_args() at the moment.

get_args() will also get default arguments from the parent function, but this easy to implement.

**SOLUTION:**

thanks Hong Ooi, the key to using match.call seems to be providing both the call *and* the definition of the function you want to find out about. A slightly modified, anonymous-friendly version of get_args is below for posterity

```
get_args <- function () {
as.list( match.call(
    def = sys.function( -1 ),
    call = sys.call(-1)) )[-1]

}
```

This version finds the function further up the call stack, grabs its definition and call, and matches parameters to its arguments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
get_args <- function()
{
    cl <- sys.call(-1)
    f <- get(as.character(cl[[1]]), mode="function", sys.frame(-2))
    cl <- match.call(definition=f, call=cl)
    as.list(cl)[-1]
}
```

The key here is to set the `definition` argument to `match.call` to be `get_arg`'s calling function. This should (hopefully!) work for the general case where `get_args` can be called from anywhere.

Comment: interesting answer, but unfortunately get_args has to be a zero-variable argument. I agree this way would make life easier, but the function (albeit with a lot of modification) is going to be used in production code for CRAN, who won't allow .Internal calls.

Comment: See my edit to remove arguments from `get_call`. I'm still not seeing why a custom function is necessary. Maybe you should post the underlying problem as a new question, and people can help you solve it in a way that doesn't require language munging.

Comment: +1 -- Could you put the better second answer first, and perhaps even remove the initial attempt?

Comment: Done! I've also changed it so that it should work when called from anywhere, rather than only from `caller`.

Comment: The second line would be better written as `f <- eval(cl[[1]], parent.frame())`.  See also https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Expressions#standardising-function-calls