# Grabbing object names from within a function

Tags: r

The title isn't super descriptive as the problem is longer than a reasonable title I could think of could display.

I want to have a function that grabs object names from other functions that can be used as arguments in another function.  Here's a barebones attempt:

```
grab <- function(x) {
    as.character(substitute(x))
}

FUN <- function(foo, bar = grab(foo)) {
    bar
}

FUN(mtcars)
```

Here I's want `FUN` to return the character string "mtcars" but it returns "foo".  How could a make a grab function that does this (I want to do this because I'm going to use this as the default to a txt/csv etc file.  It's a convenience setting.

Here are some unsuccessful attempts (but I want to have a generic grab function):

```
FUN2 <- function(foo, bar = as.character(substitute(bar))) {
   bar
}

FUN2(mtcars)

#==================

FUN3 <- function(foo, bar) {
    if(missing(bar)) bar <- foo
    as.character(substitute(bar))
}

FUN3(mtcars)
```

Real life-ish example:

```
real_example <- function(obj, file = grab(obj)) {
    write.csv(obj, file = sprintf("%s.csv", file))
}
```

Comment: Feel free to edit or edit title to make this more clear.

Comment: This question looks very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754367/using-substitute-to-get-argument-name-with

Comment: @Frank did you get any of those responses to work?

Comment: @TylerRinker I haven't tried everything, but this roughly does the same thing: `(function(x,y=get_args()))('mtcars')` where `get_args` is from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256834/getting-the-arguments-of-a-parent-function-in-r-with-names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try `sys.call` to get access to the parent call:

```
## "which" is the number of the argument of interest
grab <- function(which) {
  ## which + 1, because [1] == name of function/call
  ## and arguments are 2:n
  as.character(sys.call(-1L)[which+1L])
}

FUN <- function(foo, bar = grab(1L)) {
  bar
}

FUN(mtcars)
# "mtcars"
```

Comment: This is the behavior I am looking for.  I'll hold off checking as the answer in case others have a better option (i.e., someone points out something faulty with this).

Comment: +1. Yeah, as Tyler says, if there's nothing wrong with doing it this way (instead of passing the name "mtcars" and using `get`), I might use this, too.

Answer (score 6):

How about this?

```
grab <- function(x) as.character(x[["foo"]])
FUN <- function(foo, bar=grab(match.call())) { bar }

FUN(mtcars)
# [1] "mtcars"
```